# Refresh control on orientation change?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, refresh

I have a custom panel control, built in MainPage.xaml.cs, and I want it to redraw itself when the orientation changes (because it needs to measure the width of the display to look how I need it). I haven't found any way how to do this anywhere online :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare this in your class

```
private SimpleOrientationSensor _orientationSensor;
```

then use it like this

```
_orientationSensor = SimpleOrientationSensor.GetDefault();
        if (_orientationSensor != null)
        {
            _orientationSensor.OrientationChanged += delegate 
            {
                 // do whatever you need here
            };
        }
```

_orientationSensor must be member of class, otherwise will be collected by GC and event wont fire